# Find all index of list containing a value Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, indexing

I have 2 lists

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,3]
lst2 = [1,2,3]
```

I am trying to see the index elements in `lst` are in `lst2`. Currently I am doing;

```
ind = []
for x in lst2:
    if x in lst:
        ind.append(lst.index(x))
```

I realize the problem is that `lst.index(x)` only returns the first occurrence of the element so `x=1` will always return `lst.index(1) = 0`.

Is there a way to return all the indexes that contain the element?

Comment: These kind of operation look like they want to be implemented with sets. What the actual purpose of finding the index?

Comment: I have predicted data and observed data, stored in DataFrames. I need those indexes to find when the dates are the same in both indexes so I can compare several different filed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use something like

```
ind = [[i for i, value in enumerate(lst) if value == x] for x in lst2]
```

I don't know a purpose of this operation, but it might be more useful to use dict comprehension:

```
ind = {x: [i for i, value in enumerate(lst) if value == x] for x in lst2}
```

because in this case you will have output like that: `{1: [0, 5, 7], 2: [1, 6, 8], 3: [2, 9]}`, which might be easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you asked for:

```
ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) for y in lst2 if x == y]
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?  Search for "Python method enumerate".